# How to target all ages 65+ when create AdSet via FACEBOOK GRAPH API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/special-ad-category/ I can see that I can set age_max to 65+. And on the facebook acocunt, when I create AdSet I see in options age_max 65+. But in docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/targeting-restrictions/ I can see that maximum value is 65 years old, that I can set via marketing API. Please tell me, why in one place it's says age_max 65 and in another places it's says that age_max 65+?

And how can i target all ages 65+ when create AdSet via Facebook GRAPH API?

Comment: Have you _tried_ setting `65+` via API yet?

Comment: @CBroe, yes I tried to set 65+ via API, but got the next error: "The type integer is expected but a type string was received with value 65+.".

Comment: Try setting age_min=65 and do not set age_max. From the doc: `Set age to the default values: age_min defaults to 18 and age_max defaults to 65+.`

Comment: @Matteo, I tried this, but after creating when I get this AdSet via API, I get next results:
"age_max": 65,
"age_min": 65.
I don't see in the response value 65+.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Facebook documentation which sometimes can be misleading and contradictory between pages...

For future people who will see this post, if you do not specify an `age_max` in targeting params it will target people from `age_min` to `150` years old.

If you try to send `age_max: "65+"` to Facebook it will be refused since Facebook API only accepts integers for `age_min` / `age_max`.